# Default camera images directory path Android

Tags: android

I am a bit confused on where and how Camera images get stored. So I have an API 22 emulator ran on an SD and the below code will only work if ran using an SD card. I then take a couple of pics and see the pictures in the gallery and the `camFiles` array will get populated.

However, it does not work with API 23/24 emulators even with SD card. Is there a way to get the default camera directory that'll work for any API level?

```
File cameraDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString());
File[] files = cameraDir.listFiles();

//gets the 'Camera' directory
File finalCamDir = files[0];
File[] camFiles = finalCamDir.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the default camera directory that'll work for any API level?

Not really. There is no single "default camera directory". There are thousands of Android devices, with hundreds of *different* pre-installed camera apps, in addition to camera apps that users install themselves. It is up to the developers of those camera apps to decide where to save photos on the device.

`DIRECTORY_DCIM` is a recommended starting point. Some camera apps will put photos directly in this directory. Others, such as Open Camera, will use a subdirectory off of `DIRECTORY_DCIM` (e.g., `OpenCamera/`). Others are welcome to store their photos wherever they want, not necessarily involving `DIRECTORY_DCIM`.